# What does +9/7.2V mean?

Tags: voltage, schematics

I have a schematic of some electrical components and something is marked +9/7.2V.  What exactly does that mean?  I presume the 7.2V means 7.2 volts, but what about the +9/ part?

It is a PB Board for powering some fans in a plasma television.  The number is for the connection of the fans to a small board.  Since i am not a great expert on these things (hence the possibly simple question), I don't really know how else to explain it.

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the "something"?

Comment: My guess would be that the device is a six-cell battery; six NiCd or NiMH cells will provide about 7.2 volts, while six ZnC or alkaline cells will produce about 9 volts.  The device probably expects six batteries to be installed, and is prepared to operate correctly with anything between 7.2 and 9 volts.

Comment: Post a picture! It would help tremendously.

Comment: @supercat - why not post this as an answer so that people can vote for it.

Comment: @Joe: Did someone post a rude comment under your answer?  I never saw either.  I posted a comment rather than an answer because, at the time I replied, the question was rather vague and I didn't want to put up an "answer" without more information about what was really being asked.

Comment: @supercat - I accused Joe of stealing your answer.

Comment: @stevenvh - That was rude. If supercat wanted to answer he would have. I don't think Joe 'stole' anything.  And certainly, nothing of value was lost except an answer that could be accepted by the poser.

Comment: @AngryEE - Maybe it wasn't nice. But that was what it looked like to me; Joe posted his answer after I suggested to supercat to post *his* comment as an answer.

Comment: @stevenvh: It is rude to accuse someone of stealing absent evidence of deliberate intent.  If the answer seems to duplicate another "answer", it's fine to post a comment indicating that the answer seems similar to another; perhaps the person writing the answer meant to provide more detail than the original answer (and may or may not have gotten around to doing so).  If it's similar to a comment, that's probably only worth pointing out if the comment contains some interesting information that the answer lacks.

Answer (score 3):

7.2V at 1.2V per cell is a 6 cell battery.

9V at 1.5V per cell is a 6 cell battery.

It is most likely able to handle that range, so it can deal with NiCd/NiMH cell or standard Alkaline cells on battery powered instances.

Edit: Looks like this is a duplicate of what supercat posted in the comments.  Sorry I missed that.